# Passing a URL from an HTML form to a cURL process

Tags: php, html, forms, curl, post

I am looking for the best way to submit a website URL, through an HTML form, to multiple cURL commands(currently in shell script form) that will be used to check HTTP status(302, etc..), pull headers, and follow redirects. so using basic cURL functions for checking remote web-server statuses. This is for the benefit of confirming that the random websites in question can be currently confirmed as accessible. Again, these variables would need to be defined dynamically via a form of some kind, and not set as a static variable/arg via a script.

I have been able to work this out using PHP and bash scripts from the terminal, but I have no idea what the best process would be for passing a URL from an HTML form, to a server-side script, and then onward to a shell process for cURL... or even if that is the best option, honestly. I am also aware that PHP may not be the best option for this process, as it's not necessarily the safest way to accomplish this.

What I would like to do is use the following HTML form to submit a URL to the following cURL commands, as they exist in my bash script... have them run, and then echo back on the website with the result of the status of the provided URL.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="domain" size="35" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

cURL commands:

```
curl -Isk $domain | grep HTTP | cut -d ' ' -f2

curl -LIs $domain --max-redirs 10 | grep 301 | wc -l

curl -LIs $domain --max-redirs 10 | grep -i Content-Type
```

Edit:: This is the PHP script I am using from the terminal. It works fine. I've been trying to pass the value for $domain from an HTML form to this script, and then to my cURL bash script, which is not working. I am not sure where I am going wrong with this.

```
<?PHP
$domain = "google.com";
$command = "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh";
$output = shell_exec($command . " " . $domain);
echo "$output";
?>
```

This is my test.sh bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
domain=$1
output="$(curl -Isk $domain | grep HTTP | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
echo "$output"
```

Like I said, real simple and works like a champ form the terminal.. From HTML form, regardless of what I've tried... nogo. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: If you have already tried out to solve this problem using PHP, whats the real problem? If it is working, just do it that way :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I need to submit the URL from a website form and not just the terminal. It works with the following PHP, sans escapearg/escapecmd, but I cannot get it to work properly via my HTML form... I've tried several different things, to no avail. I've edited my original question to include my PHP script, which is working with a static value for the $domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and got it working inside of PHP itself. When I posted the original question, I had no idea that PHP had it's own cURL lib available. Here is what it looks like in working order. I'm using the same HTML form as before.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($_POST['domain']);
curl_exec($ch);

   if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
      switch (http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
         case 200: echo 'HTTP code: ', $http_code, '-Success', "\n";
         break;
         default: 
         echo 'HTTP code: ', $http_code, '-Success', "\n";
      }
   }

curl_close($ch);
?>
```